EF .NET 6 Data Annotations with database-first: cannot make annotations work
Here's a model class (generated by scaffolding, nothing changed):
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EFDBFirst.Models
{
    public partial class Product
    {
        public Product()
        {
            OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
        }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; } = null!;
        public int? SupplierId { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }        
        public string? QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }
        public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public short? UnitsInStock { get; set; }
        public short? UnitsOnOrder { get; set; }
        public short? ReorderLevel { get; set; }
        public bool Discontinued { get; set; }

        public virtual Category? Category { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
}

In order to preserve data annotation attributes after running scaffold-dbcontext, I assumed I would

Create a Metadata class, like so:

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace EFDBFirst.Models
{    
    public partial class ProductMetadata
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = @"Qty/Unit is required")]
        [Display(Name ="QPU")]
        public string? QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }
    }
}


Create a partial Product class where I link the metadata class:

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EFDBFirst.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ProductMetadata))]
    public partial class Product
    {
    }
}

But the display name doesn't show, and the required attribute isn't enforced.
Things I've already done:

Clean and Rebuild
Cleared the browser cache AND tried a different browser
Close and re-open Visual Studio 2022
Ensured that the namespace and class accessibility match exactly

BTW, if I add the attribute directly into the original model class, everything works as expected.
Any ideas? I can't for the life of me figure out what's (not) going on here....

MetadataType seems to be outdated, could you pls try ModelMetadataType instead?

That did it. Thanks!!

MetadataType is outdated, and we shall use ModelMetadataType instead. Get OP's confirmation that it can solve the issue.
